# Localhost suddenly stopped working after php update

Tags: php, macos, localhost, apache2

Alright, I'm working on a project locally, and I made the mistake of installing  grunt, which required ruby installation, and sass etc.. Well Brew must have updated something else because my local environment stoped resolving.

After some digging I found the answer and had to reinstall php5.6 (I know, I know) but the prject I'm working on specifically requires it. After reinstalling 5.6 everything started working until suddenly, and seemingly inadvertently, my local environment stopped responding again.

I get this is vague but here is all the info I have. 
I'm running dnsmasq so I have a .loc address for my sites. 
apachectl configtest says "Syntax OK"
localhost:8080 works, however nothing us with that port routes
the last log in the apache error_log is: AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

any clues would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE--
I ran apachectl -V

```
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.37_1"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/usr/local/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/usr/local/etc/httpd/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf"
```

This showed me that the httpd.conf file I was updating was not the one listed in the SERVER_CONFIG_FILE. When I updated this file to listen to port 80, it fixed the port problem, however, now when I go to one of my .loc addresses I get:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Also, Where is the Error log now?

Comment: Sounds like it's the Apache server that keeps shutting down. Try restarting Apache. Use `apache2ctl stop` and then `apache2ctl start` (I've noticed that using `restart` doesn't always work as expected).  If that don't work, try reinstalling Apache.

Answer (score 0):

So in case anyone is wondering how this turned out.

After running apachectl -V I discovered that the httpd.conf file I was originally updating, was not the one being loaded into apache. I found the correct one and made sure I had listening 80.

This solved the original problem but then I was getting a server error when I navigated to my project. this is because the project has a HTACCESS file and I didn't have the mod_rewrite module loaded into the new httpd.conf file. Once I uncommented this line it worked.

My php still doesn't work but that because of Mongo but that's another story. Hope this helps some people.